# How to know if Youtube User is verified or not

Tags: api, youtube, account

I need to know whether a Youtube user defined is "Verified" or not. This information is not on the API so I tried with curl/file_get_content to get the source code of the page but Youtube blocked my connection from my server and returned me this:

> (Starting from line #88) Sorry for the interruption. We have been receiving a large
>   volume of requests from your network.
>
> To continue with your YouTube experience, please enter the  verification code below.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I have several bugs... On the API Youtube I can get the ID Google Plus of the Channel Youtube refered.

After I get this ID, I can go to the API Google Plus and found if this people is verified or not like this :

- http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2015/05/13/150513030741753689.png

This line return me a boolean true or false but it's working half the time :

Check this ID Google Plus : 110195395364554964153 
He have an account verified, but the API return me "Verified : False"

Then check this ID Google Plus : 116623617560812527856
He have an account verified and the API return me "Verified : True"

---

After this, I was looking for search a people with YouTube API but I have a problem, I searched "Pascal Obispo" and Youtube return me this :

youtube.com/results?search_query=pascal+obispo&filters=channel&lclk=channel

He don't found "pascalobispoVEVO" and I don't understand why ? I can found it if I search like this :

youtube.com/results?filters=channel&search_query=pascal+obispo+vevo&lclk=channel

But this is not practical.. Anyone have a solution?

---

Thanks, sorry for my English that's not my best langage and I have not the reputation for post the links and image in flat sorry !